# WotC Product Identity and Design

Tags: dnd-5e, ogl, intellectual-property

I have a simple question, at least simple for people who understand legalities better than me. The way I understand the OGL and SRD, is that you can use anything from within and sell it without restrictions. That is, without using anything listed under product identity. And this is as simplified as it gets in my head.

For example, a Lizardfolk can be used since the monster is in the SRD, but a Lizardfolk Shaman cannot, since he isn't. That much is clear. The question comes now for the design.

I am glad that things like 5e LaTeX and GM Binder exist. But can one really make his documents look exactly like the WotC ones? Like the red splatter on the cover or the fonts inside? Are these things not product identity?

Another question is about copying material from the SRD. Can one, let's say, write a campaign setting that complies with the SRD, and include inside this campaign setting some magic items or monsters from the SRD? And by include I mean full text, one to one matching. The artwork can be different.

Thanks in advance for any possible answers.

Comment: I recommend this be broken into 2 questions. This question should probably be *Is Wizards of the Coast [trade dress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trade_dress) product identity?* then pose another like *Does the SRD permit users to republish parts of the SRD itself word for word?* (or however you want to phrase that second question—I think it may need to mention the OGL).

Comment: @HeyICanChan Excellent suggestion, I'm voting to close for "needs more focus", both of those are valid questions.

Answer (score 6):

When you use the OGL, you can use anything that Wizards of the Coast has released as open-game content. You can use it verbatim, just copied and pasted right out of the SRD—in fact, that’s pretty much the entire point, it ensures all the wording is consistent and third-party publishers don’t have to awkwardly try to word things in some arbitrarily different manner to avoid copyright infringement (which probably wouldn’t work anyhow).

And really, Wizards of the Coast *can* release whatever they want as open-game content, at least so long as they either own it or have it under some license that is compatible with re-licensing under the OGL. But, for example, most of their art is done by independent contractors—I don’t know what the terms of that work are, but it would be pretty normal to not buy the art’s copyright, and instead just buy a license to include it in specific publications. So unless that license included re-licensing it under the OGL—and it almost certainly would not—Wizards of the Coast could not legally make that art open-game content. This kind of thing (not for releasing stuff as open-have content, but for including things in new publications) has gotten them in trouble in the past, and even right now—there are [ongoing court cases](https://www.polygon.com/2020/10/19/21523673/dragonlance-authors-weis-hickman-sue-wizards-of-the-coast-dungeons-and-dragons) alleging that their recent use of Dragonlance and other properties exceeds their license to use those materials.

So art is pretty much never open-game content. It doesn’t suit the purposes that they had in mind when they created the SRD (since players don’t need to reference art and other third-party publishers should get their own art) and they probably don’t have the legal right to make most of it open.

What about fonts, page design, backgrounds, that “red splatter”?  Those are all art, and subject to everything I just said—but maybe they may have more reason for WotC go to the effort to allow you to use them, and something like the “red splatter” may be more likely to have been made in-house (so they wouldn’t have to worry about their own licensing issues). And many fonts are already available under (other) free licenses—if Wizards of the Coast used a free font, they can’t stop you from picking the same one. So it is more plausible that these things might possibly be released as open-game (or otherwise free) content.

However, I can’t find anywhere that Wizards of the Coast *actually has* released these materials as open-game content. Just because they *could* doesn’t mean they *did*, and I’m not finding anything saying they *have*.

More importantly, perhaps, if it is theirs and they have chosen not to say anything to \$\text{5e }\LaTeX\$ or GM Binder, that may imply that they accept this kind of usage regardless of licensing—until you actually go to court over something, copyright is almost entirely handled via agreements between the rights-holder and those who would use it, either formally via a license or informally via whatever the rights-holder doesn’t put a stop to. Note, though, that if any of this is not open-game content (or otherwise available under a formal license), Wizards of the Coast (or whoever the actual rights-holder is) would always have the right to assert themselves and tell those folks to stop using those materials—contrary to popular belief, ignoring it does not water down their copyright. That can be a thing with trademark, but nothing we have discussed has involved trademark (though you’ll notice \$\text{5e }\LaTeX\$ using the phrase “world’s most popular role-playing game”—*that* is done to avoid using Wizards’ trademark).

Assuming the worst-case scenario, that these are not free materials, and Wizards of the Coast (or another rights-holder) does assert those rights, the first step in asserting those rights would be to send a cease & desist letter. This isn’t a legally-required step or anything, and for really flagrant copyright infringement a rights-holder might not bother, but for something like this, where it isn’t necessarily clear that something is infringement, or that the people infringing knew it, or that the infringement has actually affected the value of Wizards of the Coast’s property, an actual lawsuit is going to be long, expensive, and unlikely to achieve anything more than a court order to take the infringing material down. So they’ll start by just asking you to take it down *without* going to court. And then whoever is doing the infringing will comply, because of course they will, no one wants to go to court over this. And hopefully whoever that is will spend some effort to re-do things without the offending material (removing the “red splatter,” say, and replacing it with something of their own design that fulfills a similar purpose but is visually distinct), and put it back up.

You as a consumer of these products won’t ever be affected. Copyright prevents people from distributing the copyrighted work; it has no bearing on *receiving* it.

By the way, you mentioned Product Identity, which I have mostly avoided—because it’s not particularly relevant here. For the purpose of the above discussion, Product Identity is just stuff that is not open-game content. The only distinction between something that is just not mentioned at all in an OGL, and stuff that is specifically called out as Product Identity, is that when you agree to OGL, you agree not to use Product Identity—even in ways you could normally use it without any license at all. For example, if I wrote a fantasy novel and included lizardfolk who were shamans, and even included the phrase “lizardfolk shaman,” none of that would be copyright infringement (unless I started referencing very specific things about the D&D lizardfolk shaman’s stats, *maybe*). But if I’m writing material under the OGL, I can’t use lizardfolk shamans *at all*, not even with my own invented stats.